# How to flush Spring Data JPA before calling stored procedure?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I have JPA Entity (lets say `Foo`) for which there's `FooRepository` defined as extension of `CrudRepository<Foo, Long>`. Repository has few custom methods and among them there is a method (let's say `initFoo`) that maps to stored procedure with `@Procedure` annotation. Now in service layer there is a method that looks pretty much like this (heavy oversimplification):

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.setId(5)
f.setName("Bar");
FooRepository.save(f);
FooRepository.initFoo(f.getId());
```

Calling this method results in an error from stored procedure. Upon close inspection (constraint violation: key `foo_id=5` does not exist) it appears, that entity `Foo` doesn't end up in database right after `FooRepository.save()` completes. Most probably Entity Manager decides there is no rush and keeps the entity in memory/cache.

The question is: how to convince EM to flush that particular entity to db? I'd like to avoid wiring up `EntityManager` in service layer and calling `flush()` directly. I've tried annotating stored procedure method with `@Modifying`, but it appears it only works with `@Query` methods. Any sane way to have such issue resolved?

Spring Boot (with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) 1.3.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `CrudRepsitory` you can use `JpaRepository` which contains method `saveAndFlush()`